# PROCEDIMIENTO ALMACENADO CON DOS TABLAS

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, stored-procedure, subconsultas

Necesito de su ayuda nuevamente, Estoy practicando almacenamientos almacenados pero estoy estancado en esta pregunta , por mas que investigo y intento hacerla no doy con la forma de resolverla y necesito de su ayuda y explicación para así seguir repasando. El ejercicio es el siguiente;

**

### Crear un procedimiento almacenado para poder registrar una comida enviado los siguientes parámetros: nombre, nombre de la categoría y precio. El id de la comida se debe generar dentro del procedimiento. Procedimientos almacenados para consultas con parámetros

**

Mis tablas son las siguientes;

Categoría

````
```CREATE TABLE CATEGORIA
(
  IDCATEGORIA INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
  NOMBRE VARCHAR(100)
)```
````

Comida

````
```CREATE TABLE COMIDA
(
  IDCOMIDA INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
  NOMBRE VARCHAR(50),
  IDCATEGORIA INT REFERENCES CATEGORIA(IDCATEGORIA),
  PRECIO REAL DEFAULT 0.00
)```
````

El procedimiento que intente hacer
Primero intente hacerlo en forma de consulta para entenderlo mejor y luego intente hacer un procedimiento que no funciono.

````
```CREATE OR ALTER PROC EJEM_PRO(
@NOMBRE VARCHAR(100),
@CATEGORIA_NOMBRE VARCHAR (100),
@PRECIO REAL

)AS
BEGIN 
    SELECT COMIDA.NOMBRE,COMIDA.IDCATEGORIA,COMIDA.PRECIO FROM CATEGORIA INNER JOIN
    COMIDA ON COMIDA.IDCATEGORIA = CATEGORIA.IDCATEGORIA WHERE CATEGORIA.NOMBRE= @CATEGORIA_NOMBRE

    INSERT INTO COMIDA (NOMBRE,IDCATEGORIA,PRECIO)
    VALUES(@NOMBRE,@CATEGORIA_NOMBRE,@PRECIO)

END```
````

Estaría agradecido si me ayudarían con la resolución del ejercicio y una  explicación si no es molestia. (Cabe recalcar que no es ningún deber , estoy practicando ejercicios por cuenta propia) Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero. El enunciado no parece tener sentido conforme a la definición de las tablas.

Dice:
`El id de la comida se debe generar dentro del procedimiento`

Si la primary key de tabla es identity el id no se genera en el procedimiento, se genera automaticamente con la inserción, por eso no parece el objetivo del enunciado. Lo que parece que solicitan es un id que no tenga la propiedad `identity` activada.

Dejando esa parte a un lado.

Para poder insertar un registro en la tabla de `comida`, tiene que haber previamente un registro en la tabla `categoria`.

```
Insert into categoria (nombre)
values( 'caramelos');
```

Ahora ya podemos insertar filas de `comida`, para la categría `caramelos`.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC EJEM_PRO(
@NOMBRE varchar(100),
@CATEGORIA_NOMBRE varchar (100),
@PRECIO real
)AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @ID_CATEGORIA INT;
    SET @ID_CATEGORIA= (SELECT TOP(1) IDCATEGORIA FROM categoria WHERE NOMBRE = @CATEGORIA_NOMBRE);
    
    IF @ID_CATEGORIA IS NULL
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR (N'LA CATEGORIA SOLICITADA NO EXISTE',11,1);
    END
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO COMIDA (NOMBRE,IDCATEGORIA,PRECIO)
        VALUES(@NOMBRE,@ID_CATEGORIA,@PRECIO);

END
```

Existen muchas maneras de enfrentarse al enunciado, y esta puede ser una. Si observas el procedimiento, verás las diferencias con el tuyo. Quitando la Select que no nos aporta valor, de momento.

Para poder insertar una comida, dado que la definición de la tabla dice  `IDCATEGORIA INT REFERENCES CATEGORIA(IDCATEGORIA),` necesitamos el id de la categoría que no tenemos. Ya que solo tendremos el texto correspondiente al campo `nombre`;

Por tanto creamos una variable para contener el `id_categoria` buscado, y lo hacemos. Pero ojo como puede haber más categorias que tengan el mismo nombre, porque no es una columna con una restricción `Unique`, busco la primera usando el operador Top. Asumiendo que esto no debería de ocurrir, pero evitando el posible error de que así fuera.

Nota: Este punto puedes trabajarlo bastante para buscar otras maneras de hacerlo.

Luego evaluamos si la categoría ha sido encontrada. Caso que no lo fuera devolvemos un error al usuario.

Por último insertamos el registro con el `@id_categoría`, y no con el texto que viene como parámetro.

Ejecutando el procedimiento:

```
exec dbo.EJEM_PRO 'prod1','caramelos',5.0
```

Ok.

```
exec dbo.EJEM_PRO 'prod2','embutidos',5.0
```

[image: Result]

```
exec dbo.EJEM_PRO 'prod3','caramelos',5.0
```

Ok

```
Select * from dbo.comida;
```

[image: Result2]

[RaisError](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/05/15/raiserror-como-funciona-como-se-utiliza/)

**Nota Adicional**: Para avanzar en programación, hay que quitarse de encima las frases de "No Funciono" o me dió "Error". Y ser mucho más explícito. Los que leen la pregunta no saben lo que significa no funcionó. Pudo ser que el procedimiento no se ejecuta, que no lo encuentra, que no tiene los suficientes parámetros, que no ha sido invocado con los parámetros adecuados, que los valores no son los apropiados, que la sentencia Select no estaba bien realizada, que los criterios de la misma eran excluyentes ......y un monton de cosas más. Lo mismo si da un error, no vale con decir y fue error. Hay que indicar y el motor me devuelve el error 12425 y su mensaje. Porque en vista del código y del mensaje de error, si lo hubiera, las cosas pueden tener un sentido, que el que está programando no ve.

Comment: Mas claro que el agua , creo que aun me falta practicar lo que es la lógica de los procedure. Muchas gracias Javi ,Eres un crack♥